# F# compiler requires project reference, but method is private

Tags: methods, compiler-errors, f#, project, private

The F# compiler gives an error saying I must add a project reference because the type I'm using has a method argument that lives in that project. *But this method is private!*

I have the following project structure:

*Program -> Library -> SubLibrary*

*SubLibrary* contains this:

```
namespace SubLibrary

type Widget = { Value: int }
```

*Library* contains this:

```
namespace Library

open SubLibrary

type Banana =
    { Value: int }

    member private x.TakeWidget (w: Widget) = ()
```

*Program* contains this:

```
open Library

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv

    let banana = { Value = 42 }
    0
```

I get this error:

```
error FS0074:
The type referenced through 'SubLibrary.Widget' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
You must add a reference to assembly 'SubLibrary'
```

But the `TakeWidget` method is *private*!

I tried changing `Banana` into a class, rather than a record, but that made no difference.

As an experiment, I created a C# version of *Library*, called *CLibrary*:

```
using SubLibrary;

namespace CLibrary {
    public class CBanana {
        int m_value;

        public CBanana(int value) {
            m_value = value;
        }

        private void TakeWidget(Widget w) {
        }
    }
}
```

Then I changed *Program* to use `CBanana` instead of `Banana`:

```
open Library

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv

    let banana = CBanana 42
    0
```

Now I don't get an error. In fact, with C# I can make that method public, and so long as I don't try to compile a call to it, there is no error.

Why is the compiler insisting I add a reference to SubLibrary? Sure, I could just go ahead and do what it tells me to do, for a quiet life, but *SubLibrary* is a private implementation detail of *Library*, which should not be exposed to *Program*.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, when I tried with a class instead of record, it did the trick (F# 3.1):

```
type BananaClass (value:int) = 
    member private x.TakeWidget (w: Widget) = ()
    member x.Value = value
```

You can work around it with a record as well - you need to move the private member into a separate module and have it as a type augmentation:

```
type Banana = { Value: int }

module Ext =
    type Banana with
        member x.TakeWidget (w: Widget) = ()
```

Compiler won't complain about the missing dependency until you open the `Ext` module.

I don't have a good idea why the compiler was complaining in the first place. Probably one of its quirks. I couldn't find anything seriously suspicious in the generated IL (other than a surprising fact that F# compiler marks both private and internal members as internal in the IL - this turned out to be of no consequence here).

Comment: I'm also using F# 3.1 (VS 2013). If `Banana` is a class, you can compile a call to the constructor, but if you try to access the public `Value` property, that's when you'll get the error. In my case, I need the method to be intrinsic, because it needs to be discovered using reflection, so an optional extension is no good to me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Somewhat unsurprisingly, the spec states that "The CLI compiled form of all non-public entities is `internal`."

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this to me looks like an error I have raised an issue here, https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/86. So you'll be able to track feedback from there.